# Python parsing string

Tags: python, string, parsing

Can somebody please help me with this one in Python, I have a string that looks like this:

```
Comm IF Ver 1.18c Port  TCP-1
>R5281H0000
>L0121 @g
>E0042A1204C0000
>S@QT@L0121 @g
>S0339E1512
>
```

I would like to get a string from that output that would look like this:

```
R5281H0000   L0121 @g   E0042A1204C0000   S@QT@L0121 @g   S0339E1512
```

Comment: Is this from a file? or a string with many lines?

Comment: It is a string with 6 lines, so string.count('\n') gave the result of 6.

Comment: Which is weird because I see 7 lines?

Comment: It is ok to have 6 `\n` for string with 7 lines. The last line does not have `\n` :) see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a `string`:

```
a = " \
    Comm IF Ver 1.18c Port  TCP- \
    >R5281H0000 \
    >L0121 @g \
    >E0042A1204C0000 \
    >S@QT@L0121 @g \
    >S0339E1512 \
    >"
```

Consider using `split` to get your result

```
b = a.split('>')[1:-1] #1 is to exclude the first one, -1 to exclude the last one
```

Resulting in list with the elements which you want.

If you want to combine them into a `string` with some spaces, use `join`:

```
c = " ".join(b)
```

**Edit step-by-step explanation:**

What `split` does it "splitting" your string into `substrings` based on its delimiter. In this case the delimiter being `>`, thus it changes a long string:

```
a = " \
    Comm IF Ver 1.18c Port  TCP- \
    >R5281H0000 \
    >L0121 @g \
    >E0042A1204C0000 \
    >S@QT@L0121 @g \
    >S0339E1512 \
    >"
```

Into a list of string having the following elements:

```
'Comm IF Ver 1.18c Port  TCP-' #element no 0
'R5281H0000' #no 1
'L0121 @g' #no 2
'E0042A1204C0000' #no 3
'S@QT@L0121 @g' #no 4
'S0339E1512' #no 5
'' #no 6
```

Then when you use the slice indexes `[1:-1]`, you cut off the first and the last element:

```
'below is b

'R5281H0000' #no 0, previously 1
'L0121 @g' #no 1, previously 2
'E0042A1204C0000' #no 2, previously 3
'S@QT@L0121 @g' #no 3, previously 4
'S0339E1512' #no 4, previously 5
```

Then finally, `join` will make those strings in the list back into one string separated by space `" "`

```
R5281H0000      L0121 @g      E0042A1204C0000      S@QT@L0121 @g      S0339E1512
```

Comment: Can you please explain to me how exactly b = a.split('>')[1:-1] works, it is doing what I want but would just like to see how is it doing it?

Comment: @Dominik explained. Hope it makes you understand better. :)

Comment: I am still having new lines on the end of each line? \r\n

Comment: @Dominik if you `join` with withspace `" "` then you don't have it anymore. If you `join` with `\r\n`, then it will have it. It depends on how you `join` them`. In my case, I `join` with `" "`, thus the new lines are gone.

Comment: To get rid of the newlines  `c = (" " *3).join([s.strip() for s in b])` (sorry for the `" "*3`, I wasn't able to display three spaces in a string).

Comment: @Ian yeah it was not working so I just went through the list and striped '\r\n' while concatenating everything together with '+'
So this is what worked for me:
`final = ''
str = str.split('>')[1:-1]
for item in str:
    item = item.rstrip('\r\n')
    final = final + item + '   '`

Answer (score 0):

What I gather is that you want to join each line that starts with `>` with three spaces, but don't include the `>`.  The following is how to do that:

```
print("   ".join(s.lstrip(">") for s in string if s.startswith(">")))
```